# How to stop lubridate dropping the hour when it's just gone midnight

Tags: r, lubridate

How do I get lubridate to keep the hour when the time is e.g. 00:30:42? `hms()` wants to output `30M 42S`, whereas I want `0H 32M 40S`.

```
library(lubridate)
hms("00:32:40")
[1] "32M 40S"
```

The reason I need this is because I'm using the time to put together a datetime:

```
ymd_hms("2022-09-13 0H 40M 32S")
[1] "2022-09-13 00:40:32 UTC"
ymd_hms("2022-09-13 40M 32S")
[1] NA
Warning message:
All formats failed to parse. No formats found.
```

Comment: How are you putting together the datetime to parse? That is, how are you formatting the parsed time object?

Answer (score 2):

Depends a bit on what your original data is, as strings...

```
ymd("2022-09-13") + hms("00:32:40")
ymd("2022-09-13") + as.duration("32M 40S")
```

or as @king_of_limes already suggested in his answer:

```
ymd_hms(paste("2022-09-13", "00:32:40"))
```

All will output:

```
[1] "2022-09-13 00:32:40 UTC"
```

If we truely want to work with one string that has a time lacking the hours, we can create a ymd_ms function that is not existing in lubridate. It is a bit more robust than needed, but it supports now both (HH:)MM:SS as well as (H) M S formats.

```
# lets create some not existing lubridate style function ymd_ms()
ymd_ms <- function(x) {
  ymd_hms(gsub("(\\d )(\\d{1,2}M|(\\d{1,2}:\\d{1,2})$)", "\\10H \\2", x, perl = T))
}

v <- c("2022-09-13 40M 32S", "2022-09-13 3H 40M 32S", "2022-09-13 2H 40:32", "2022-09-13 12:40:32", "2022-09-13 40:32", "2022-09-13 11H 40:32 PM", "2022-09-13 11:40:32 PM", "2022-09-13 11:40:32 AM")

ymd_ms(v)

# [1] "2022-09-13 00:40:32 UTC" "2022-09-13 03:40:32 UTC" "2022-09-13 02:40:32 UTC" "2022-09-13 12:40:32 UTC" "2022-09-13 00:40:32 UTC" "2022-09-13 23:40:32 UTC" "2022-09-13 23:40:32 UTC"
# [8] "2022-09-13 11:40:32 UTC"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have two strings

```
a <- "2022-09-13"
b <- "00:32:40"
```

then you can do

```
lubridate::ymd_hms(paste(a,b))
```

Comment: This doesn't answer OP's question.

Comment: It yields the result OP was looking for in their stated usecase. There is no argument you can pass to `hms()` to keep the leading zeroes, so I was presenting an alternative.

Comment: There's no corresponding argument to `hms` because that's a *parsing* function, not a *formatting* function, so the argument would make no sense there.